# Are 使用 and 施用 interchangable?

Tags: word-choice

In my on-going quest to understand the difference between initially indentical-looking words, I hereby bring you: 使用 vs. 施用! Both seem to mean 'to apply something' and it appears to be acceptable to both 使用化肥 and 施用化肥. 
Maybe I have hit a genuine synonym this time?! If history is anything to go by, probably not, but it's a fun game, eh? :-)
Hashamyim

Comment: If you found that 施用化肥 example from Pleco, you can see that 施用 also means 'execution (of an action); 施行', so they're interchangeable but not *fully* interchangeable.

Comment: bkrs **使用**  [use] 使人或物为某种目的服务
使用打字机很熟练  make use of; use; employ; apply; wear:
禁止使用 forbid the use of
使用不当 unwise use of
介词的正确使用 the correct use of prepositions
使用火力 employ fire
使用极便 utmost in convenience
留待将来使用 for future use  **#560**  同义: 应用, 利用, 采用, 施用
**施用** [use] 使用; 采用
施用一种新的操作法 use; employ; apply:
施用化肥 apply fertilizer
这种杀虫剂用水稀释后直接施用在田里。 This pesticide is diluted with water and applied directly to the fields. **#30622**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

施用 = use; apply; implement (usually to a target)

使用 = use; operate (with or without target)

- When someone "施用武力" or "施用毒氣"，  there are always specific targets the action is applied to

Example: 對示威者施用武力; 對村民施用毒氣 use force against demonstrators; use gas on the villagers (*you can replace 施用 with 使用 in these two examples*)

- When someone "使用工具" or "使用武器" there may or may not be a specific target the action is apply to.

Example: 祇有小數動物會使用工具/武器 Only a few kinds of animal know how to use tools/weapons ( *you cannot replace 使用 with 施用 in this example because there is no specific target the action is apply to*)